# ¿Cómo cambio uno de mis campos según el resultado de una subconsulta? Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subconsultas

Lo que quiero hacer es una consulta que indique los proyectos que se encuentran dentro de una tabla y que tengan una tasa promedio una vez que tenga dichos proyectos de la consulta, lo que tengo que hacer es que a través de otra consulta puedo multiplicar un porcentaje a un campo desde Otra tabla donde debería existir ese mismo proyecto.

```
select CASE
    WHEN estimador.Clave = 'Perfiles' THEN (select gasto.[Importe Banco]*0.5 from SN_INT_PartidasGasto as gasto where gasto.[Clase de Coste]='FSW' and estimador.IdProyecto=gasto.[ID Proyecto] and AmbientePRE='PRE')
    WHEN estimador.Clave = 'Puntos V1' THEN 'Puntos V1'
    WHEN estimador.Clave = 'Puntos V2' THEN 'Puntos V2'
    ELSE 'Sorry, no match.'
    END AS CATEGORIA from tb_Estimador as estimador where estimador.IdProyecto in (select gse.FolioSantec from db_Incurrido.dbo.GSE_Real as gse where gse.FolioSantec=estimador.IdProyecto and estimador.Clave!='Tarifa Promedio')
```

Con la consulta anterior obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
>, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Comment: Depende que valor quieras. Puede ser un valor aleatorio, el máximo, el mínimo, la suma o el promedio. Lo siguiente es que tendrás un problema si no conviertes el dato a una cadena.

Comment: No podes poner (select gasto.[Importe Banco]*0.5 from SN_INT_PartidasGasto as gasto where gasto.[Clase de Coste]='FSW' and estimador.IdProyecto=gasto.[ID Proyecto] and AmbientePRE='PRE') si ese select devuelve mas de una fila. un subselect solo puede devolver una fila.

Comment: Evidentemente, existen varios gastos, al menos para un proyecto de tu consulta. Si existen varios gastos, que es lo que debe hacer tu consulta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estudia funcionalmente que registro quieres.

Y elige aquí en el where:

where estimador.IdProyecto in (**select gse.FolioSantec** from db_Incurrido.dbo.GSE_Real

- Si el dato no es relevante opta por poner un top 1 de gse.FolioSantec
- Si has de considerar un registro vigente usa un nuevo filtrado para traer el de fecha máxima

Son 2 posibilidades pero lo que te comento es que estudies funcionalmente qué y para qué y ya luego decide como sacar el dato.

Un saludo cordial!